# Does MySQLi OOP look exactly like PDO? Or do they have their differences?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I've attended a PHP class. In the class it was mentioned that MySQLi OOP is just some wrapper classes around traditional MySQLi. Is that true? If we don't have wrapper for PDO so what exactly PDO (PHP data object) is?

Answer (score 1):

> Does MySQLi OOP look exactly like PDO?

No.

> Or do they have their differences?

Yes.

> MySQLi OOP is just some wrapper classes around traditional MySQLi. Is that true?

It rather makes no sense. There is no "traditional MySQLi"  and mysqli is not a wrapper.

> what exactly PDO (PHP data object) is?

Semi-wrapper. Quite ugly one, but still way better than mysqli which is a mere raw API

Comment: I admire your patience.